# How do I find a replacement radio?

Tags: parts, audio

I have a 1995 Mazda Protege LX and the radio has been dead for a while, so I want to replace it. The installation/removal looks pretty simple. How to I find a radio that will work as a replacement radio? Something I can order online is preferable, but maybe that isn't possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Crutchfield.com](http://www.crutchfield.com/), you can put in your make model and see many radios that will fit. [This is the what the search turned up when I put in your car info.](http://www.crutchfield.com/g_300/Car-Receivers.html?tp=5684) 
It looks like you have a standard DIN radio, so any standard DIN radio will fit without an adapter kit. You will need a special tool like the one pictured below to remove the radio.

[image]

Here is an example of radio removal

[image]

You'll also want to get a vehicle specific wiring harness adapter [like the one pictured below](http://www.crutchfield.com/p_120707901/Ford-Mazda-Receiver-Wire-Harness.html?tp=2977) so you can simply plug the aftermarket radio into the factory harness. **NEVER** cut and splice the wires into the main harness.

[image]

All of the above is assuming you want an aftermarket radio for the replacement. If you want a factory replacement I would recommend [Carpart.com](http://www.carpart.com/) although my search doesn't pull up any radios for your vehicle. You can also check local salvage yards, and other online salvage sites for a used radio